# Is sale of luxurious goods with a huge profit margin haraam?

Tags: halal-haram, business

Sale of luxurious goods with a huge profit margin.  The price is set by the manufacturer and not the seller or marketer.  Is it haraam to promote such goods?  As far as I know selling only essential items with a profit is haraam.

Comment: Why would you think it's haraam in the first place? The general rule in *fiqh* is that everything is permissible unless proven otherwise.

Comment: Jazaka mullah khairah

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.